# Unable to add roles to a user in Azure AD for native app (WPF)

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-active-directory

got a WPF app that I would like to authentication using Azure AD (got a sample that makes it work). Once authentication is done, I'd like to get a list of roles assigned to a user. I have added roles to the manifest of the app registration and saved it. I was then trying to follow this link :

[Assign a user or group to an enterprise app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal)

to assign roles to users but Users and Groups option is not available at all in the enterprise application for this app. It is available for web app, but not native. Am I missing something? Anyone knows of a good example that would authenticate user in WPF and retrieve roles (I have been looking into graph API to get user groups by so far have been unsuccessful).

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't miss anything.

This is because that **Native client** registrations are **multi-tenant** by default. You don’t need to take any action to make a native client application registration multi-tenant. It means that you can sign in this application with any Users in Azure AD with some configuration. So, you wouldn't see Users and Groups in Native client in Enterprise Applications.

However,you can assign the users **(without roles)** to native applications by using cmdlets in PowerShell:

```
$appId = (Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString “<Your App's display name>”).AppId
$user = Get-AzureADUser -searchstring "<Your user's UPN>"
$servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter “appId eq ‘$appId'”
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id ([Guid]::Empty)
```

More information about the command for assigning a user to an application role, please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Is it possible to add users **with roles** to native applications via PowerShell or Azure CLI? I am unable to even add users let alone specify roles for a native app in Azure Portal.

Comment: +1 looking for exactly the same thing...how to assign roles to users. Please post an update if you find something!